# How to export JQGrid in excel with .xlsx format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, export

I have jqGrid with grouped columns and I want to export jqGrid in excel (.xlsx) format on click of a button.

I am able to export the table in excel with `.xls` format but this is the old format and I want to export in `.xlsx` format.

below is the code.

```js
$('#excel').unbind().click(function (){                      
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';   ?                              
  var table = $("#hiddenGrid"); 
  var table_html = '<table><thead><style> table, td {border:thin solid lightgrey}</style><tr><th></th><th>Group</th><th>Sort</th><th>Item ID</th><th>Description</th><th>Tag</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Cost Total</th><th>Sell Total</th><th>Qty Shipped</th></tr></thead></table>';
                             
  table_html = table_html + table[0].outerHTML;
  a.href = data_type + ', ' + escape(table_html).replace("%u", '-');
  a.download = 'GridExport.xls';
  a.click();
});
```

I have tried changing `GridExport.xls` to `GridExport.xlsx` but no luck.

is there any third-party tool that I have to use to export the excel in .xlsx format? or any other solution?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: Hi Tony, I using "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.5/jquery.jqgrid.min.js" free version